# 自身のクラスをhas_manyとして持つクラスの子供側の特定のhas_manyの数がゼロの要素を取得する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

すいません、タイトルをできるだけわかりやすく書こうとしたのですが意味不明になってしまいこれ以上うまく書けませんでした。

`Phrase`という自分自身を`Translation`をいう名前のクラスがあり、そのクラスが`has_many`で`Voice`というクラスを持つのですが、特定の`Phrase`の`Translation`が存在し、その`Voice`が一つもない要素を取得したいのですがクエリがかけずに躓いています。

#### app/models/phrase.rb

```
class Phrase < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :translatabilities
  has_many :translations, through: :translatabilities
  has_many :voices
end
```

#### app/models/translatability.rb

```
class Translatability < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :phrase
  belongs_to :translation, :class_name => 'Phrase'
end
```

以下の様なクエリを試してみたのですが、これでは`Translation`として取得したモデルの`Voice`が一つもなくても`Phrase`側の`Voice`が存在すると取得対象外になってしまいます。

```
Phrase.includes(:translations).
    where.not(translatabilities: {phrase_id: nil}).
    includes(:voices).where(voices: {phrase_id: nil})
```

どのようにすれば「`Translations`が存在し、そのどの`Translation`も`Voice`持たない」要素をとってこれるでしょうか？

Rubyの式で書くと

```
phrase.translations.present? && phrase.translations.all?{|t| t.voices.empty? }
```

が真になる要素を抜き出したいです。

Comment: テーブルがどのような状態の時にどのような結果になって欲しいのか、今はどうなるのかがわかりにくいです。「Phraseという自分自身をTranslationをいう名前のクラス」というのは意味不明です。

Comment: 中間テーブルのモデル内容を記述し忘れていたので追記しました。

Answer (score 1):

こういうケースはSQLで書いてしまうのが手っ取り早いと思います。

```
class Phrase < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :translatabilities
  has_many :translations, through: :translatabilities, class_name: 'Phrase'
  has_many :voices

  # 特定のPhraseのTranslationが存在し、そのVoiceが一つもない要素を取得したい
  scope :with_translation_without_voice, -> {
    query = <<-SQL
EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM translatabilities ta
  INNER JOIN phrases t
  ON t.id = ta.translation_id
  WHERE
  ta.phrase_id = phrases.id
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM voices v
    WHERE
    v.phrase_id = t.id
  )
)
    SQL
    where(query)
  }
end
```

以下はテストコードです。

```
require 'test_helper'

class PhraseTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test '特定のPhraseのTranslationが存在し、そのVoiceが一つもない要素を取得したい' do
    translation_with_voice = Phrase.create! name: '翻訳、Voiceあり'
    translation_with_voice.voices.create! name: '音声１'
    translation_without_voice = Phrase.create! name: '翻訳、Voiceなし'

    phrase_with_translation_and_voice = Phrase.create! name: 'フレーズ、音声付きの翻訳あり'
    Translatability.create! phrase: phrase_with_translation_and_voice, translation: translation_with_voice

    phrase_with_translation_without_voice = Phrase.create! name: 'フレーズ、音声なしの翻訳あり'
    Translatability.create! phrase: phrase_with_translation_without_voice, translation: translation_without_voice

    phrase_without_translation = Phrase.create! name: 'フレーズ、翻訳なし'

    phrases_by_ruby = Phrase.all.select {|phrase| phrase.translations.present? && phrase.translations.all?{|t| t.voices.empty? } }
    assert_equal [phrase_with_translation_without_voice].map(&:name), phrases_by_ruby.map(&:name)

    phrases_by_scope = Phrase.with_translation_without_voice
    assert_equal [phrase_with_translation_without_voice].map(&:name), phrases_by_scope.map(&:name)
  end
end
```

schema.rbは以下のようになっています。

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160104001330) do

  create_table "phrases", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "translatabilities", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "phrase_id"
    t.integer  "translation_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",     null: false
  end

  add_index "translatabilities", ["phrase_id"], name: "index_translatabilities_on_phrase_id"
  add_index "translatabilities", ["translation_id"], name: "index_translatabilities_on_translation_id"

  create_table "voices", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "phrase_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "voices", ["phrase_id"], name: "index_voices_on_phrase_id"

end
```

コードはGitHubにもアップしています。

https://github.com/JunichiIto/not-exists-sandbox

ちなみに「生SQLは絶対に書きたくない、Arelを駆使してなんとしてでも生SQLを避ける！」と考える人もときどき見かけますが、僕は「そんなに無理せずSQL書けばいいやん」と考える人です。
Arelを駆使したコードは非常に読みづらいですし、Railsのバージョンアップで動かなくなるケース（[参考](http://qiita.com/joker1007/items/5c851526e73b3bc0273a)）も何度か見てきたので。

Comment: 詳しい解説ありがとうございます。はい、SQLの方がわかりやすい時はSQLを使おうと思っています。ただすいません、質問文が不明瞭でした。正しくは「`Translations`が存在し、そのどの`Translation`も`Voice`持たない」でした。初めから書いておけばよかったのですがRubyの式でどのような`phrase`が欲しいかを記述しておきました。